# Spring Gateway - how to assert a request which is forwarded to a service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gateway

My Spring Boot Gateway application routes incoming request to internal micro-services. Using filters it adds some headers, like this:

```java
exchange.getRequest().mutate().header("foo", "bar");
```

How to write a test which asserts the request after modifications applied by the gateway?

My tests looks like this:

```java
stubFor(get(anyUrl()).willReturn(aResponse()
.withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").withStatus(200).withBody(response)));

// (...)

webClient.post().uri("/my/endpoint")
.bodyValue(json).exchange()
.expectStatus().isOk()
```

How to test that `"foo=bar"` header is actually forwarded to the underlying micro-service? It's not passed back to the gateway so adding ".expectHeaders()" to the test won't work.